# Serenity BDD JVM How do i do action if the showl scenario fails or pass?

Tags: automation, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, testrail

I build this framework with serenityBDD and JVM. I need to write results in test rail with an api that if my scenario fails, then to trigger this api. I cant add it in the scenario steps becuase if it fails before it might not get to that api. Is there a way for me to trigger this endpoint if the whole scenario fails? I also need to trigger it if it passes.

Example: If i cant get past putting in my credentials below, then i need to trigger api.

Scenario:Verify that i land on home page

Given I navigate to website

When I log in using my credentials

When I click on home page

Then I verify I am at home page